# Use lib file in non-StartUp project, in c++ solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, lib

I try to use functions implemented in .lib file, in c++ solution with multiple projects (I use Visual Studio).
I need to use that functionality in one of the non-StartUp projects in the solution, but I don;t have Linker tab in project's properties.
What properties should I set in order to use the .lib file?

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties and navigate to **Librarian** -> **General**. Then, add your `.lib` to **Aditional Dependencies**. Also, you should complete **Aditional Library Directories** to tell the linker where to find your `.lib`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to use `Add Reference`.

1,Open the shortcut menu for the  project in Solution Explorer, and then choose Add > Reference.

2,The Add Reference dialog box lists the libraries that you can reference. The Projects tab lists the projects in the current solution and any libraries they reference.

I suggest you could refer to the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=vs-2019#to-use-the-functionality-from-the-static-library-in-the-app